# Creating/Running a docker container from within a c# program (under mono)

Tags: c#, linux, mono, centos, docker

I have a manager program on my docker host which allocates resources to process incoming requests.   We'd like to try and put one of our c# processes off into a docker container (running locally for now).

I've found the command line which would run docker and invoke my c# program :

```
/usr/bin/docker run -d -p 9001:9001 centos-foo /opt/mono/bin/mono /opt/prog/MyExe.exe --no-console --http_port 9001
```

When I build up that command using the System process class and call start, it doesn't work.   My host program is c# running in mono under the apache user on centos 6.5.

```
Process mProcess = new Process();
mProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/bin/docker";
mProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " run -d -p " + mPort + ":" + mPort + " centos-foo /opt/mono/bin/mono " + mParameters.Get(AppParameterKeys.PROVIDER_EXE) + " --no-console --http_port " + mPort;
mLog.Info("Starting ServiceProvider via command : " + mProcess.StartInfo.FileName + " " + mProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);
mProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
mProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
mProcess.StartInfo.UserName = "root";
mProcess.StartInfo.Password = mSecurePasswd;
mProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(mParameters.Get(AppParameterKeys.PROVIDER_EXE));
mLog.Info("Starting ServiceProvider from directory : " + mProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory);
mProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
mProcess.Exited += OnProcessExited;
if (mProcess.Start())
{
   mLog.Info("Start returned true");
}
...
```

I realize I may have problems with the Exited callback, but right now its not even creating the docker container.   I can see the full command in the `log4net` output and if I paste that into the command line it works run.

I have the whole block wrapped in a `try/catch` but it doesn't throw and `start()` returns true.  It just doesn't actually start anything.

So, I'm unsure if I am actually getting root privs to run docker using the `username/password startinfo`. I also don't know if because my original program is running in mono if its trying to run docker in mono too and that's failing.   I'm really quite confused by `start()` returning true and not throwing exceptions.

I'm now looking into invoke the HTTP interface to docker, but I'd rather start it using this mechanism.   What am I missing or doing wrong here?